# Switch Twitter Accounts in Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

There's add-ons for Firefox to do this, switching twitter accounts without having to sign-in 3-5 times a day is really time saving if you have more than 2 accounts, CookieSwap do the job, is there any possible extension can do the job for safari?

Answer (score 1):

There is no add-ons on Safari who is doing that.

**Chrome :** 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swap-my-cookies/dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama

**Mozilla :**
https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cookieswap/

By the way, I think you have to post your wish here : https://www.reddit.com/r/SomebodyMakeThis/